# How to find the last row of a print area?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a print area, I need to find the last row that is in the print area. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, here's my set print area.

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:F100"
```

Comment: Does @user3598756's code not work? I'm just curious, because IMO it's a little more elegant and less clunky.  Although I would recommend setting a Range to that first, but I'm just curious why my answer is elected. (Not a complaint or anything obviously, just wondering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a range, then just count the rows in the range:

```
Sub t()
Dim printRng As Range, lastRow As Long

Set printRng = Range("A1:F100")
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = printRng
lastRow = printRng.Row + printRng.Rows.Count - 1
Debug.Print "Last row of print area is: " & lastRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use this function:

```
Function PrintAreaLastRow() As Long
    With Range(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea)
        PrintAreaLastRow = .Rows(.Rows.count).row
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Print area range with worksheet name as input

```vb
Function GLR(wsName As Range) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim printedArea As Range
   
    ' Check if the worksheet exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0
   
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
       ' Get the printed area of the specified worksheet
       On Error Resume Next
       Set printedArea = ws.Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea)
       On Error GoTo 0
       
       If Not printedArea Is Nothing Then
           ' Count the number of rows in the printed area
           GLR = printedArea.Rows.Count
       Else
           ' Return 0 if no printed area is set
           GLR = 0
       End If
   Else
       ' Return 0 if worksheet not found
       GLR = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It may help if you added some further text commentary, however, as it stands your `GLR` function appears to return the number of rows in the print area instead of the last row number as per the question ... of course, these can be the same if the print area starts at row 1. Also your comment "worksheet name as input" doesn't seem correct, rather the `wsName` paramater requires a Range where the first cell holds the name of the particular worksheet?